# Linear Algebra used to solve hotel room light switch question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a special suite of rooms designed with light switches in an odd way.  Our goal is to turn off all of the the lights.

There are 25 rooms in the suite arranged in a square of five by five rooms:

```
1  2  3  4  5 

6  7  8  9  10

21 22 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25
```

If you switch the light switch in any room, it toggles the lights in the adjacent room.  For example,

-assuming all of the lights are on and you switch the switch in room 1, the lights in room 2 and 6 are turned off and there is no other change in the status of the lights.

-or assuming all of the light are on and you switch the switch in room 18, the lights in room 13, 17, 19, 23 are all turned off and there is no other change in the status of the lights.

1. Assuming all of the lights are on, please advise on how to turn off all of the lights.  You can use a web app for row reduction.
2. Assuming all of the lights in even number rooms are on, please advise on how to turn off all of the lights.

After row reduction, we get a free column where,

$$x_4 =  t$$

$$x_1 = -2 + t$$

$$x_2 =  2 - t$$

$$x_3 =  1 - t$$

Can anyone help out with the rest?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic: Did you just reduce the matrix with the room numbers as entries?

Comment: What counts as an adjacent room?  Are vertically adjacent rooms adjacent?  Are diagonal's adjacent?

Comment: @Carser That info was deleted in a previous edit.  I reintroduced it to help with the clarification.

Comment: @Lovsovs that's correct, row reduced using room numbers as entries.

Comment: @James I don't think that makes any sense. For instance, what does $x_i$ represent?

Comment: @Lovsovs I understand what you're getting at.  Professor suggested to use a web app for row reduction instead of doing it by hand to save time.  My approach was to obtain a solution set first and then go from there but I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 5):

Here, all work will be done in $\Bbb F_2$, that is, nothing but zeroes and ones.

Construct a $25\times 25$ matrix $A$ such that $A_{i,j} = \begin{cases}1&\text{if button}~j~\text{toggles light}~i\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Let $x$ be a $25\times 1$ matrix corresponding to what our button selections were.

Then given an initial configuration of lights, $v$, one has $v+Ax$ is the resulting configuration.

If we have a desired final configuration, $r$, then we wish to solve the matrix equation $v+Ax=r$ for the vector $x$.  If it so happens that $A$ is invertible, then this will simply be $x=A^{-1}(r-v)$

Instead of going through the effort of explicitly writing out the $25\times 25$ matrix (*it is incredibly tedious*), I will show with an example how it works for the $9\times 9$ case corresponding to a $3\times 3$ grid of rooms with lightswitches.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

As it so happens, is in fact invertible over $\Bbb F_2$ in this case, but that is not always the case.  Here we have $A^{-1}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&0&1&1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&1&0&0&1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Using this matrix, a starting configuration (say, all lights on) and a desired final configuration (say, all lights off), we can compute $A^{-1}(r-v) = x$ which in this case would be $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\0\\1\\0\\1\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, telling us that to switch the lights from all on to all off in the $3\times 3$ grid, we can flip the switches in rooms $1,3,5,7,9$.

---

In the case of the $5\times 5$ grid, requiring a $25\times 25$ matrix, we approach similarly.

Our matrix is:

`1100010000000000000000000
1110001000000000000000000
0111000100000000000000000
0011100010000000000000000
0001100001000000000000000
1000011000100000000000000
0100011100010000000000000
0010001110001000000000000
0001000111000100000000000
0000100011000010000000000
0000010000110001000000000
0000001000111000100000000
0000000100011100010000000
0000000010001110001000000
0000000001000110000100000
0000000000100001100010000
0000000000010001110001000
0000000000001000111000100
0000000000000100011100010
0000000000000010001100001
0000000000000001000011000
0000000000000000100011100
0000000000000000010001110
0000000000000000001000111
0000000000000000000100011`

Unfortunately, as alluded to earlier, this matrix happens to not be invertible.  That is to say, given a starting position, there are some ending positions which are impossible to reach.  There are also multiple ways to reach the same ending position given a starting position if possible to reach in the first place.  Regardless, that is not to say that the desired start and end that we are looking for are impossible.  We find that the matrix above happens to be of rank $23$.

Trying to solve the matrix equation then, $Ax=r-v$, we can try to row reduce the augmented matrix $[A~|~(r-v)]$.  If the system is inconsistent, then no solution exists.  If it is consistent, then you should be able to interpret the results of the reduced form in such a way to get one of the possible vectors $x$ which gets you the desired outcome.

---

Note: this method can be generalized for similar related problems given arbitrarily shaped grids and lightswitches which may operate differently than those given in the above problem.  Say for example where flipping a light in a room in the top row will toggle the lights in all adjacent rooms and itself, flipping a light in the second row will toggle all diagonal rooms and itself, flipping the light in room 20 toggles itself and room 1, etc...

> row reducing one finds that by flipping the switches in rooms 2, 3, 5, 7,8, 9, 13, 14,15, 16, 17,19, 20, 21, 22, we will change all lights from on to off or vice versa.  I will not bother explicitly solving the second question and leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I don't think button $i$ toggles light $i$, so that the diagonal elements in $A$ should be zero, but it doesn't really change the nature of the problem. Great answer!

Comment: @Lovsovs indeed, my matrices used interpret the statement as "toggles the lights in the adjacent rooms *and the room itself*."  As mentioned though, the method employed is very general and can be modified for however the lights happen to work in any generalization or modification to the problem.

Comment: It is also worth noting that $A$ will always be symmetric (at least for these specific rules), so it is sufficient to just write out the upper/lower triangle.

Comment: @Lovsovs in the generalization to the problem, that is no longer true.  Perhaps switches in rooms will only affect the room and the room to its right.  Either way, my initial interpretation of the rules matched the rules to an electronic game from 1995 called [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)).  Interestingly, the method I used to solve seems to be similar to [a paper](http://web.archive.org/web/20100524223840/http://www.math.ksu.edu/~dmaldona/math551/lights_out.pdf) published in '98.

Comment: True, and interesting find!

Comment: @Actually, I have a question: I can't seem to make sense of that $v+Ax$ should be the final configuration. $v$ is a $25\times1$ matrix with entries being $0$ or $1$, and so is $Ax$, so surely some entries of the sum can become $2$? This should of course be interpreted as $0$, but can't it be done from the LinAlg alone?

Comment: @Lovsovs note the first line: We are working in the field $\Bbb F_2$.  That is, we are working in the scenario that $1+1=0$.  Linear algebra is written very generally.  Usually people are used to working with the scalar field being $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, but in this instance, we are going to use $\Bbb F_2$, the field with two elements.  We get to specify what the field is. This is because we only care about things being on or off, and flipping a switch an odd number of times is the same as flipping it once while flipping a switch an even number of times is the same as flipping it no times.

Comment: Ah, have yet to study group theory - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will solve the simpler $2 \times 2$ case, but the technique is the same for  $5 \times 5$

So we have a matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 \\
a_3 & a_4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where each $a_i$ is a hotel room. To show whether the light in the room is on or off, we will let $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$

By your description of the problem, turning on the light in each room results in the following configurations

$$
A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0
      \end{pmatrix} \\
A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      0 & 1
      \end{pmatrix} \\
A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      1 & 1
      \end{pmatrix} \\
A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 1 \\
      1 & 1
      \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now we want to find a linear combination of $ \left \{ A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4 \right \} $ such that

$$
\sum_{i}c_iA_i = \begin{pmatrix}
                 1 & 1 \\
                 1 & 1
                 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This involves solving a linear system of 4 equation in 4 unknowns

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3 \\
c_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Solving this system gives

$$
\mathbf{c} = \begin{pmatrix}
             1 \\
             1 \\
             1 \\
             1
             \end{pmatrix}
$$

So for the simple $2 \times 2$ case if we just flip each switch once we will turn off all of the lights.